# Right-align headers cut off in DataGrid

Tags: c#

I have a DataGrid with a few columns that need to be right-aligned. When they are aligned, the last few characters are cut off (i.e. "Total" becomes "Tota") because the header becomes so far aligned right.

Googling and looking around it seems that the most common solution is to add something like spaces with a low-profile character (i.e. "  ."), however I'd like to avoid this workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though this issue can be solved by using a DataGridView which is an updated version of the DataGrid that is in .Net 2.0

More information can be found on : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171628.aspx